# How to add a data if the database is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm trying to add a number to a column called ID in my database. What should happen is when there no data in the database this script will insert the first line with the ID numbered as 1 but the issue is it's not working.

I think my checking of null data is the issue can one of you help me by pointing out what should I do.

**My code**

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('connect.php');

$lastId = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM poiinfo");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($lastId);

if (is_null($row['ID'])){

    $nId = $row['ID'];
    $nId = 0;
    $nId = $nId++;

    $addId = "INSERT INTO poiinfo(`ID`) VALUES ('$nId')";
    mysql_query($addId);

}else {

    $lId = $row['ID'];
    $lId = $lId + 0;
    $lId++;
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your table structure? And ... why are you populating IDs manually?? use `auto increment` for that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to do this. `AUTO_INCREMENT` will pick the next ID for you.

Comment: Why don't you use an `auto_increment` index for ID?

Comment: I think you should be using an `auto_increment` id so that you don't have to manually increment the ID yourself.

Comment: @ajacian81 I'm using auto increment the issue is I'm using uplodify to upload an image what happens is when the uplodify insert the name of the file in to the DataBase it get inserted to a new line. So what I'm doing is getting the last line ID reduce it by one then update that line ID. So when there's no ID that structure dosent work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query which you are executing

```
INSERT INTO poiinfo('ID') VALUES ('$nId')
```

will most likely fail because the `columnname` was enclosed by single quote. The quote should be reomved or replace it with backtick, eg

```
INSERT INTO poiinfo(ID) VALUES ('$nId')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO poiinfo(`ID`) VALUES ('$nId')
```

and so the question is, *when do I use backtick*? It's you are using a name which is on the list of MySQL's reserved keyword,

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

and lastly, you must pass the variable containing the query in `mysql_query()`

```
mysql_query($addId);
```

Comment: Also, the function call doesn't reference the variable in which the query is stored. `mysql_query("addId");` should be `mysql_query($addId);`

Answer (score 0):

you will have to reset the auto increment field `ID` so that you can insert 1 if table is empty